# How to fix the errors in Firefox without reinstallation

Tags: software-installation, firefox

After installing the actualization more or less one week ago, I started having problems with Firefox, which seems to me connected rather with some error in installation of the updates than with the actualization itself.

Some websites doesn't display the text. The graphics are there, sometimes the title also. Other websites (this one for instance) display correctly.

The easiest to do would be to reinstall Firefox, but unfortunately I don't remember the last password to my Gmail account. I was using the Firefox sync  and unfortunately with the crush, it's not my current but previous password which is saved.

I can open my account only using my usual device, and if I try to open Gmail using password saved in Firefox sync, it says "wrong password". I've checked in Firefox's preferences - the Gmail password saved there is the previous one.

How can I check what is wrong Firefox installation and repair the errors?

Comment: It is unclear why you need gmail to install firefox.

Comment: @user3169 I don't need gmail to install firefox, but if I reinstall it I will loose definitely my account.

Comment: I think you at least need to describe what the updates were (if Firefox, from what to what version). There have been some other posts recently regarding font issues after updating to FF 57. Also which Ubuntu version?

Comment: To be honest I'm not able to say what the update was, I've just installed all suggested updates. Current version of FF is 57.0.1. System is Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is not wired signes (as in other posts concerning problems after installing updates) but the lack of text...

Comment: @maria Re-install the mozilla firefox without losing your gmail password >> Is this you are looking for ?